# Problema com insert condicional

Tags: php, mysql

Boas estou com o seguinte problema estou a fazer um insert condicional para não duplicar entradas na tabela porém não me está a inserir nada

Codigo

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO visitas_estabelecimento (user_id, estabelecimento_id) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['user_id']."', '".$row_cat->id."')
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM visitas_estabelecimento 
    WHERE estabelecimento_id='".$row_cat->id."' and user_id='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'");
}
?>
   $row_user_id=mysql_fetch_object($result_verifica);
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row_user_id->id;
```

Comment: Já verificou se a saída da string que vc está executando dentro do `mysql_query` está retornado o esperado? Provavelmente alguma variável esta vazia. Se tiver tudo ok, execute o comando em algum `SGBD` e veja o que acontece

Comment: Sim ja verifiquei e sai como esperado

Comment: Poderia colocar o código onde `$_SESSION['user_id']` é inicializada;

Comment: Já coloquei nao coloquei tudo pois senao teria de colocar o login todo

Comment: Se ajudar eu imprimi o retorno da query INSERT INTO visitas_estabelecimento (user_id, estabelecimento_id) VALUES (38, 1) WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM visitas_estabelecimento WHERE estabelecimento_id=1 and user_id=38)